# How to Pivote using Group By in Pandas ( Which may Also Give Sparse Result)?

Tags: python, pandas

Given The Rows Contain

```
> Country , STATE, Gender, AgeGroup, Height, Weight
---------------------------------------------------
> USA     ,  IN,    M,       Child,     80,     25
> Canada  ,  OW,    F,       Adult,    164,    58  
> Canada  ,  OW,    F,       Adult,    167,    64
```

To be Pivoted with Group By As,

```
> Country , STATE, M_Child_Height, M_Adult_Height, F_Child_Height,M_Adult_Height,M_TEEN_WEIGHT
---------------------------------------------------
USA,          IN   80 , NA .. NA..  25(As_M_CHILD_WEIGHT) .NA , NA ...
-- --         --  --   --   --  --  --  ---
```

Comment: what's supposed to happen to the two rows that are both Canada, OW, F? Are the values supposed to get averaged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` followed by `unstack` twice and then collapse the column names. unstack creates a hierarchical column index.

```
import pandas as pd

#Create test dataset
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Country': ['USA', 'Canada', 'Canada'],
    'STATE': ['IN', 'OW', 'OW'],
    'Gender': ['M', 'F', 'F'],
    'AgeGroup': ['Child', 'Adult', 'Adult'],
    'Height': [80, 164, 167],
    'Weight': [25, 58, 64]
})

#Groupby country/state/gender/agegroup to calculate mean height and weight
out_df = df.groupby(['Country','STATE','Gender','AgeGroup']).agg('mean')

#Unstack twice to get the AgeGroup and then Gender into the hierarchical columns
out_df = out_df.unstack().unstack()

#Flatten the column names by joining the hierarchical levels
out_df.columns = ["_".join(a[::-1]) for a in out_df.columns.to_flat_index()]
```

`out_df` table:

[image]
out_df